# How to create a js checkbox in flexdashboard? shinyTree does not work (R, shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, jstree, flexdashboard, shinytree

I have a problem with using shinyTree in flexdashboard. In a regular shiny app works well:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$tree <- renderTree({
    opciones = list('All'= list( 
      'Human' =  structure(list('OP1'='OP1', 'OP2'='OP2'),stopened=TRUE),  
      'Mouse' =  structure(list('OP3'='OP3'), stopened=TRUE)))
    attr(opciones[[1]],"stopened")=TRUE
    opciones
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyTree("tree", checkbox = "TRUE")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, when I use it in Flexdashboard, it returns an empty tab (see this file: https://mega.nz/file/DCozwIiJ#ttcBe581FPfhINVoczfBvaXhgRlXwVSu-wd2JhXTEEY)

Do you have any idea why this could be happening and how to create a js tree checkbox in flexdashboard?

Comment: You could try `jsTreeR` instead of `shinyTree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jsTreeR` package can do more than the `shinyTree` package. And it works fine with `flexdashboard`:

[image]

````yaml
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(jsTreeR)
```

```{r}
nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "RootA",
    data = list(value = 999),
    icon = "far fa-moon red",
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "ChildA1",
        icon = "fa fa-leaf green"
      ),
      list(
        text = "ChildA2",
        icon = "fa fa-leaf green"
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    text = "RootB",
    icon = "far fa-moon red",
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "ChildB1",
        icon = "fa fa-leaf green"
      ),
      list(
        text = "ChildB2",
        icon = "fa fa-leaf green"
      )
    )
  )
)
output[["jstree"]] <- renderJstree({
  jstree(nodes, dragAndDrop = TRUE, checkboxes = TRUE, theme = "proton")
})
output[["treeSelected"]] <- renderPrint({
  input[["jstree_selected"]]
})
```


Column {data-width=400}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Checkbox tree

```{r}
jstreeOutput("jstree")
```

Column {data-width=400}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Selected nodes

```{r}
verbatimTextOutput("treeSelected")
```

### Chart C

```{r}

```
````